# Как получить адрес получателя используя recv и send?

Tags: c++, c, winsock

Я использую `recv` для приема пакетов и `send` для отправки, но когда я принимаю пакет через `recv` я не знаю адрес получателя, что бы отправить пакет через `send`.

Мне интересно как это можно сделать без использования `recvfrom` и `sendto`

Для удобства добавлю пример.

Это сервер 1

```
AmountReadServer = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); // принимает пакет от клиента

send(sock, buffer, AmountReadServer, 0); // должен отправить тому же клиенту, но клиент не получает его.
```

Это клиент 2

```
send(sock, buffer, AmountToSend, 0); // отправляет пакет серверу, тут все работает

AmountReadClient = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0); // должен получить пакет от сервера но не получает его
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99087/discussion-on-question-by-nigan------recv--s).

Answer (score 1):

Используй `recvfrom` и адрес источника принятого сообщения будет в переменной `from`

```
int WSAAPI recvfrom(
  SOCKET   s,
  char     *buf,
  int      len,
  int      flags,
  sockaddr *from,
  int      *fromlen
);
```

[Пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-recvfrom#example-code)

Comment: Мне нужно без использования recvfrom

Comment: Почему? В удп рецв никто не пользуется, не видел нигде

Comment: Я тоже не видел, но я смог сделать это, осталось только понять как определить адрес.

Comment: @Nigan, вы на удпшных сокетах выполняете send/recv?

Comment: @Nigan очень просто, используйте recvfrom) getpeername() можно ещё попробовать, но мне кажется оно для удп не должно работать

Comment: getpeername не может определить ip под recv

Comment: @goldstar_labs да

Comment: Вероятней всего нужно как то заранее определить подключения, то есть гибрид TCP и UDP
Но проблема в том что я использовать могу только SOCK_DGRAM

Comment: @Nigan если только датаграм, то только, то точно recvfrom. Не вижу чем recv лучше

Comment: @eri он на несколько микросекунд работает быстрей

Comment: Причина в том что он не хранит ip адрес и порт а передает на прямую с сокета

Comment: и в чем тут проблема?